# SQLAlchemy dynamic schema-names does not work if session is returned from try/except or with-block

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to use multiple schemas in SQLAlchemy.
Somehow it does not work properly when using context manager (`with-block`) or `try/except-block`.

This is my short execution example:

```
def import_units(schema_name: str):
    from taxes.models import Tax
    
    dbs = get_db_session(schema_name)
    dbs.add(Tax(percentage=19.00, abbreviation="abc"))
    dbs.commit()  ## during commit I get ERROR:
       ## sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "per_user.taxes" does not exist
       ## LINE 1: INSERT INTO per_user.taxes (percentage, abbreviation, de...
```

Here is how I generate the `session` and pass it with and without `blocks`:

```
def get_db_session(schema_name: str):    
    dbs = SessionLocal()
    dbs.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {'per_user': schema_name}})
    
    return dbs ## this return WORKS (translates into right schema name)

    try:
        return dbs ## this does NOT work (no translation, uses 'per_user' as schema name)
    finally:
        dbs.close()

    with SessionLocal() as s:
        s.connection(execution_options={"schema_translate_map": {'per_user': schema_name}})
        return s ## this does NOT work (no translation, uses 'per_user' as schema name)
```

If the `imports` and `session` creation can give you some data, here are they too.

```
from config.settings import SQL_DATABASE_URI
import warnings
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine(SQL_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True, future=True)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, future=True)
warnings.filterwarnings("always", category=exc.RemovedIn20Warning)
```